# R - dplyr::case_when evaluating incorrectly

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm attempting to write a `dplyr::case_when` statement to catch errors within a function and replace them with a different variable. Unfortunately, `case_when` doesn't seem to be evaluating an empty variable correctly and returns the empty variable instead of the replacement.

The code below should have an output of `replacement variable`, but instead I get `character(0)`.

```
x <- character(0) #is_empty(x) evaluates as TRUE
y <- "replacement variable"

case_when(
   is_empty(x) ~ paste(y), #replace with y if no x value
   TRUE ~ paste(x)) #otherwise use x
```

Any thoughts for why this might be case and/or how to fix it?

I've tried altering the order of arguments within the case_when, as well as using:

```
length(x) == 0 ~ paste(y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case_when` returns a vector with a length equal to the length of the vector you pass in. So nothing in, nothing out. If you need to change lengths, you might just need a basic `if\else` statement; `case_when` is not the right function in this scenario. It is not a general purpose switch statement. It is a vectorized data transformer.

In this case you would just do

```
val <- if(is_empty(x)) y else paste(x)
```